# Defining $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}| \Delta y|$ in this wiki-page.

Tags: calculus

I'm trying to make sense out of this wikipedia articles procedure in defining arc length of a curve.. here is my observation:

Step 1. The hypotenuse of the triangle in the arc's partition is $\sqrt{\Delta x^{2} + \Delta y ^{2}}$.

Step 2. The arc length given is the limit of line segments equal to $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}| \Delta y| = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{i=1}^{n}  \sqrt{\Delta y^{2}}$. At this step I supposed that it's the same hypotenuse of the triangle, and $\Delta x^{2} \in \sqrt{\Delta x^{2} + \Delta y ^{2}}$ and deduced $\Delta x^{2}$ approaches $0$ as the number of partitions go up. But $\Delta y^{2}$ also approaches $0$ so why is it left over or why is $\Delta x^{2}$ not in the formula?

[observations from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGUqd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they're just talking about two different things. Their definition of $L(f)$ is the total vertical distance traveled by $f(t)$, where you count upward movement and downward movement as positive. What you're looking for would be more like what they discuss in "Finding arc lengths by integrating". The organization of the Wiki page does seem kind of confusing, but what do you expect for a community of largely anonymous volunteers (like, um, this one)?

Comment: I just do not see why in one case the length is $\int_{a}^{b} | 0 + f'(x)|dx$ and another it is $\int_{a}^{b} | 1 + f'(x)|dx$ now.

Comment: @arclengths I think it's because the definitions are different in the two different cases. In the first case, we can think of the integral as the miles of wear I put on my shoes when I pace back and forth on a one-dimensional path with $f(t)$ being my position at time $t$. In the second case, we can think of the length of chalk outline someone would trace out following my path along the two-dimensional curve $(x,f(x))$.

Comment: I'm finding that $\int_{1}^{2} 2xdx =3 = L(x^{2})$ while $\int_{1}^{2}\sqrt{1+(2x)^{2}}dx >3$... I might not be able to find out the problem between understanding this can you think of something else?

Comment: @arclengths I think we might be going in circles at this point. Your integrals work out to different values, as indeed they must since the integrand of one is strictly greater than the integrand of the other. There's no reason they should work out to the same value since they represent different mathematical concepts/definitions.

Comment: I just don't get why the vertical distance traveled is not the arc length! It isn't something I've used before in physics or calculus.

Comment: @arclengths I hope we're not still going in circles. If you buy that one is measuring the total distance traveled and one is measuring the vertical distance, then I think it's clear that they should be different. Suppose that you have someone who travels in a 2D plane, North/South and East/West. A second person duplicates their movement, but only in the North/South direction. Clearly, the second person is not moving as far. For example, if the first person runs Northeast, the second person would only have to jog North to keep pace.